# Update buttons position in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I have 4 ints (randomInt1, randomInt2, etc) that are updated with this method (the inside of the method is not important, it gives a random int from 0 to 3):

> updateInts();

I have 4 buttons in an ArrayList and a listener for each of them. I want that everytime a button is clicked, all the buttons get a new random position. The problem is that they keep their initial position without been updated.

```
updateInts();

buttons[randomInt1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    updateInts();
                    // do stuff
                }
            });

        buttons[randomInt2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateInts();
            }
        });

        buttons[randomInt3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateInts();
            }
        });

        buttons[randomInt4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateInts();
            }
        });
```

How can I do to get my buttons position updated ?

P.S : my method updateInts() works perfectly. The ints are updated when I call it. The problem is that the index of my buttons dont get updated.

Comment: we can´t say until we know the `updateInts` method...

Comment: You would either 1) Have to redraw your view or 2) Simply change the text or whatever is on the button

Comment: What do you mean by "they keep their initial position without been updated."? As I see 4 random ints are updated when the buttons are clicked. What else do you want to update? Maybe there are cases where randomInt1 == randomInt2, or similar case, which means you may be setting OnClickListener to the same button two or more times.

Comment: They are updated inside the listeners but not "outside". I mean the "buttons[randomInt1]" always stays the same.